# Experiencing delay when fetching 100th row

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-ruby

I am fetching all the rows from the collection and experience delay on 100th row. I understand that find method returns cursor and not all the data up front and at certain point need to fetch more data. But the 100th row is the only delay.

```
Checking images 99
Checking image 100
*pause*
Checking image 101
```

And then with no visible delay up to 100 000 image.

Used ruby script:

```
require 'mongo'

time_start = Time.now

mongo = Mongo::MongoClient.new("localhost", 27017)

db = mongo["pics"]

images = db["images"]
albums = db["albums"]

orphans = []

images.find().each do |row|
    puts "Checking image #{row['_id']}"
end

# puts orphans
time_end = Time.now
puts "Total time taken: #{time_end - time_start}"
```

[Used images collection (json)](https://education.10gen.com/static/content-10gen-devs/handouts/images.945a77b733bc.json)

`mongoimport --db pics --collection images file_name`

The questions are:

- does some data come along with the initial cursor?
- why is the only delay at 100th row? Maybe I've missed something but I don't even see IO reads at that point

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default "batch size" of the MongoDB cursor is 100 objects. Means MongoDB fetches 100 objects before fetching the next batch...that is why you see delays. All drivers should provide a method "batch_size()" or similar on the cursor object for setting and retrieving the batch size.

Comment: You are right. Setting batch_size to 500 makes it smooth. `images.find().batch_size(500).each`. Also using `mongostat` I've checked that by default at 100th row it sends me 3mb of data which is the cause of that hiccup.